# MySQL: Insert list of 100 random numbers into one field then display them

Tags: php, mysql, logic

I have a table with 500 quotes, each one has an ID from 1 to 500. This table has 2 Columns: QuoteID and Quote.

A customer orders 100 random quotes on the Order page.

I need to generate 100 random numbers between 1 and 500 and somehow insert this into the Customer table for that customer’s order. The Customer table has 2 Columns: CustomerID and QuotesOrdered.

Then, on the Display page I need to display each of these quotes. It would have to look at the 100 random ID numbers listed in the QuotesOrdered column, then pull each of these from the Quotes table to display them.

Is there a simple way to do this? Would I generate the 100 numbers into an array, then somehow insert this array into the Customer table QuotesOrdered column, then go through the array and display each quote associated with that ID number from the Quotes table?

Any help on how to logically do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure why you would need to store random numbers in a table just to then select the quotes. You can directly select 100 random quotes with the following query:

```
select quoteID, quote from quotes order by rand() limit 100;
```

---

Now if, for some reason,  you do need to persist 100 random quote numbers in the `customers` table for a given customer, then:

```
insert into customers
select :customerID, quoteID from quotes order by rand() limit 100
```

... where `:customerID` should be replaced with the id of the concerned customer.

Then when you want to display them:

```
select q.quoteID, q.quote
from customers c
inner join quotes c on c.quoteID = q.quoteID
where c.customerID = :customerID
```

Comment: The first idea would show 100 different quotes every time they refresh the page, right? I wanted to insert 100 specific random numbers into the table so they would always see the same 100 quotes and not different ones every time.

Comment: @FrostedKrispie: yes your understanding is correct. So you can go with the solution provided in the second part of my answer.